# How to Use Chaining Translation in Unix

Tags: unix

I want translate the word "abcd" into upper case "ABCD" using tr command then translate the "ABCD" to digit e.g 1234.

I want to chain two translations together (lowercase to upper case, then upper case to 1234) using pipes and also pipe the final output into more.

I'm not able to chain the second part.

`echo "abcd" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'  > file1`

Here I'm not sure how to add the second translation in the same command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in a single `tr` command; you can do it in a single pipeline:

```
echo "abcd" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr 'ABCD' '1234'
```

Note that your `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]` notation will translate more than `abcd` to `ABCD`.  If you want to extend the mapping of digits so `A-I` map to `1-9`, that's doable; what maps to `0`?

If you want to do it in a single command, then you could write:

```
echo "abcdABCD" | tr 'abcdABCD' '12341234'
```

Or, abbreviated slightly:

```
$ echo 'abecedenarian-DIABOLICALISM' | tr 'a-dA-D' '1-41-4'
12e3e4en1ri1n-4I12OLI31LISM
$
```